# Can't Convert string to JsonArray

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, gson

How do you convert this String into gson.JsonArray?

```
String s= "[["110917    ", 3.0099999999999998, -0.72999999999999998, 2.8500000000000001, 2.96, 685.0, 38603.0], ["110917    ", 2.71, 0.20999999999999999, 2.8199999999999998, 2.8999999999999999, 2987.0, 33762.0]]";
```

This is my Code:

```
 com.google.gson.*;
 public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       //Declared S here
       System.out.println("String to Json Array Stmt");
       JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
       JsonElement tradeElement = parser.parse(s.toString());
       JsonArray trade = tradeElement.getAsJsonArray();
       System.out.println(trade);
    }
```

Is this the way to convert this Collections string to JSonArray?

Comment: com.google.gson.JsonArray ;Library i am using this (gson)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To have a string value inside your JSON array, you must remember to backslash escape your double-quotes in your Java program. See the declaration of s below.

```
String s = "[[\"110917       \", 3.0099999999999998, -0.72999999999999998, 2.8500000000000001, 2.96, 685.0, 38603.0], [\"110917    \", 2.71, 0.20999999999999999, 2.8199999999999998, 2.8999999999999999, 2987.0, 33762.0]]";
```

Your code in the main() method works fine. Below is just a minor modification of your code in the main() method.

```
System.out.println("String to Json Array Stmt");
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement tradeElement = parser.parse(s);
JsonArray trade = tradeElement.getAsJsonArray();
System.out.println(trade);
```

Lastly, remember to prefix your statement "com.google.gson.*" with the keyword "import", as shown below.

```
import com.google.gson.*;
```

Comment: Here typo mistaken for import in the question .actually added in source..thanks

Comment: Is it Possible to split the JsonArray?

Comment: You mean getting the first element ([\"110917       \", 3.0099999999999998, -0.72999999999999998, 2.8500000000000001, 2.96, 685.0, 38603.0]) of JsonArray "trade"? Try using "trade.get(0)".

Answer (score 11):

I don't see the problem. This code runs fine for me:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;


public class GsonExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s= "[[\"110917\", 3.0099999999999998, -0.72999999999999998," +
                "2.8500000000000001, 2.96, 685.0, 38603.0], [\"110917\", 2.71," +
                "0.20999999999999999, 2.8199999999999998, 2.8999999999999999," +
                "2987.0, 33762.0]]";


        JsonParser  parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement elem   = parser.parse( s );

        JsonArray elemArr = elem.getAsJsonArray();
        System.out.println( elemArr );
    }
}
```

The only problem maybe is that you failed to properly escape the double quotes in your s string literal.

Comment: May i know why here we need to add /(backward slash) in front of strings?

Comment: Just I want first list only as a json array? Is it possible to pass?

Comment: The slash is to escape the " character. If you don't do it the compiler can't know you're not intending to end the string for example with a closing ". See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Comment: elemArr.get( index ) can be used to return the first element of the array for example.

Answer (score 4):

The above answers are deprecated. We have to call the static method instead. Here is the working code.

```
JsonArray outputJsonArray = JsonParser.parseString(pasteYourStringHere).getAsJsonArray();
```