# get date list from bean to receive in javascript at jsf

Tags: javascript, jsf, javabeans

How can I get the datelist from bean like this? I don't want to use "c:foreach" tag. How can I solve this? What should I write in `<ui:repeat>` tag?

```
    var date = [
    <ui:repeat value="#{timeSheetBean.leaveDatelist}" var="leavedate"varStatus="loop">  

    </ui:repeat>
         ];

    console.log("leave date list is --> "+date[1]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't want to use tag"?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I mean <c:foreach> tag.

Comment: You might consider using JSON.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478851/send-data-from-bean-to-javascript-with-json-in-jsf .